# Getting symbols error: 'ld: symbol(s) not found'

Tags: c++, symbols

I'm trying to execute this code, but I'm getting the symbol error of the title:

**configfile.cpp:**

```
#include "configFile.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <map>

configFile* configFile::getInstance(){
    pinstance = new configFile();
    return pinstance;
}

configFile::configFile(){
    filename = "/Users/myfolder/NetBeansProjects/Oier_2/config.cfg";
}

void configFile::setConfigFileName(std::string s){
    filename = s;
}

float* getConfiguration(std::string type, int size) {
    std::string data[size];
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream myfile("/Users/myfolder/NetBeansProjects/Oier_2/config.cfg");

    while (std::getline(myfile, line)) {
            std::istringstream is_line(line);
            std::string key;
            if (std::getline(is_line, key, '=')) {
                if(key.compare(type) == 0){
                    for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
                        std::getline(is_line,data[i],',');
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    float *fdata;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        fdata[i] = (float)atof(data[i].c_str());
    }
    return fdata;
}
```

And **configFile.h:**

```
#include <string>

#ifndef CONFIGFILE_H
#define CONFIGFILE_H

class configFile {

private:
    static configFile* pinstance;
    static std::string filename;    
public:
    static configFile* getInstance();
    void setConfigFileName(std::string s);
    float* getConfiguration(std::string type, int size);
protected:
    configFile();
    configFile(const configFile& orig);

};

#endif  /* CONFIGFILE_H */
```

The symbols error I'm having:

> Undefined symbols:   "configFile::filename", referenced from:
>         configFile::configFile()in configFile.o
>         configFile::configFile()in configFile.o
>         configFile::setConfigFileName(std::basic_string, std::allocator >)in configFile.o
>   "configFile::pinstance", referenced from:
>         configFile::getInstance()       in configFile.o
>         configFile::getInstance()       in configFile.o   "configFile::getConfiguration(std::basic_string
>   std::char_traits, std::allocator >, int)", referenced
>   from:
>         _main in main.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

If it's necessary: **main.cpp**:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include "configFile.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    configFile* cfg = configFile::getInstance();    

    string type = "tiempo";
    float* tiem = cfg->getConfiguration(type,3);

    for(int i=0; i< 3;i++){
        printf( " %f ", tiem[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm running a MaxOSX 10.6.8. Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 1):

These two areas are the issue:

```
configFile::configFile(){
    filename = "/Users/myfolder/NetBeansProjects/Oier_2/config.cfg";
}

void configFile::setConfigFileName(std::string s){
    filename = s;
}
```

You've declared `filename` as a static data member, so its name must always be `configFile::filename`. If you meant to use a data member, you can simply remove the `static` definition.

The difference between static and non-static data members is that with static, only one variable exists, whereas with a non-static data member there is an instance of this variable per-class. So in this case, the consequence is that with static, each instance of `configFile` would reference the same file path, whereas removing static would make each `configFile` own its own `filename` and so have its own file path.

Comment: I've removed the statics from the configFile.h file `configFile* pinstance;` and `configFile* getInstance();` But I'm  getting the following error on (in main.cpp) the line `configFile* cfg = configFile::getInstance();`. This is the error: `main.cpp:47: error: cannot call member function 'configFile* configFile::getInstance()' without object`

Comment: @Borja the same logic applies of static functions too. Static variables and methods do not belong to a given instance of a class. You'll need to remove that too.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? I've removed all the `static` from the `configFile.cpp`and `configFile.h` files but I'm still having the same error in `main.cpp`

Comment: @Borja Ok, I've read the code a little more in depth. `getInstance` is currently doing two things: assigning a static member variable AND allocating a new pointer to it. If you do want that single static instance to exist, that's fine and allowed, but in code you need to refer to it as `configFile::pinstance`. If you want to completely do away with `static`, then the callee of `getInstance` simply needs to have a local variable of `configFile*`. The pattern I think you are after here is the [singleton pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/257111) ...

Comment: The answer I linked in above provides some good reading on implementing singletons in C++.

Comment: I've left the `static` and change `pinstance` to `configFile::pinstance` on the `configFile.cpp`file and still getting the same symbol error, argh!